# While loop list index out of range - does not make sense?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, while-loop

```
s = str(input("Please enter your line of text: ").lower())
only_vowels = re.sub(r"[^aeiou]", "", s)
c = (Counter(list(only_vowels)))  
print(c)

if len(c) >= 1:
    most = c.most_common()[-1]
    result = (most[0])

    i = -2
    if len(c)>=2:
        while (c.most_common()[i][1]) == most[1]:
            result = ", ".join((result, c.most_common()[i][0]))
            i = i-1


    print("The least common vowel(s) in the inserted sentence is/are",      (result),"and it/they appear(s)",most[1],"times.")

else:
    print("You have not inserted any vowels into this sentence.")
```

The code trips out on this piece of code 'while (c.most_common()[i][1]) == most[1]:'

Any ideas why?

Comment: `c` is a `Counter`, correct?

Comment: It will be hard to understand the issue without knowing more context around the definition of `c` and `most` variables, how they are used before this snippet, etc.!

Comment: Please both review original question. I realised the issue was that my counter function was malfunctioning. Any ideas how to fix this now (original Q edited)

Comment: @LewisFirmin `c` is a `Counter` object, and is being printed as such.  `c.most_common()` will return a list of pairs of keys and values, which you can then print.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that. Have now altered some code and also edited the question...AGAIN. I have now included the entire coding. Please take a look if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

How many entries do you have in the list?
If i = -2 then you need at least to have 2 entries in order that Python could go through the list backwards.

Comment: Hi Kev, please review the original question. I have entirely edited it. I realised what the issue was and now need to work out how to fix my counter problem to enable this coding to work!

Answer (score 0):

It prints "Counter" because c is an object of type Counter.

Counter has a method to get the most common occurrences but it doesn't seem to have one for the least common. How about this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

occurrences = defaultdict(list)
vowels = "aeiou"

sentence = input()

for v in vowels:
    if v in sentence:
        occurrences[sentence.count(v)].append(v)

try:
    less_frequent_vowels = occurrences[min(occurrences)]
except ValueError:
    less_frequent_vowels = []
```

Comment: This looks promising actually. It works to retrieve how many vowels are used how many times. How would I then print the least occurrences? This may be more than one vowel though! (If e, i and o are all only used once, I need all 3 to be printed)

Comment: that's already taken into account. less_frequent_vowels is a list of what you are looking for.

Comment: try: print(", ".join(less_frequent_vowels))